# How to run iterations in Python with mini-batches of 4 pictures from a folder containing 40 pictures in total?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, yolo

I want to run my image processing algorithm on a batch of 4 images and display the output. Then again, I want to run another iteration with another batch of 4 images, until all the images in my image-containing-folder are processed. Right now, the algorithm processes all pictures in the folder as a single batch.

I will put some codes showing how I am taking images from the folder and how I am creating the list. PS I'm super beginner at this.

```
def arg_parse():
parser.add_argument("--images",
                            dest='images',
                            help="Image / Directory containing images to  vehicle detection upon",
                            default="vehicles-on-lanes",
                            type=str)
......
images = args.images
imlist = [
            osp.join(osp.realpath('.'), images, img) for img in os.listdir(images)
        ]
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347640/how-to-iterate-through-different-folders-and-perform-image-processing-turn-by-tu

Comment: There are errors in the code: `parser` is not defined, `args` is not defined, `osp` is not defined. Presumably `os` requires `import os` to be defined. The function block is not indented correctly on the first line...    these are all before the actual question is looked at.  Here is a helpful guide:    https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example    - please reformat the question as other users might otherwise downvote it.

Comment: if you want in batch then split this list to smaller lists - `imlist[0:4]`, `imlist[4:8]`, ... `imlist[n:n+4]`. and run your function(s) for every list separatelly. You could use `for`-list for this. In this situation can be useful `for n in range(0, len(imlist), 4): function( imlist[n:n+4] )`

Answer (score 0):

Simply split list into smaller sublists  `imlist[0:4], imlist[4:8], ... ,imlist[n:n+4]` and run your function(s) with every sublist separatelly

In this situation can be useful `for`-loop with `range(len())`

```
for n in range(0, len(imlist), 4): 
    your_function( imlist[n:n+4] )
```